# Compare 2 files and extract common rows into 2 separate files

Tags: python

I have 2 files

File 1:

```
| Name | Age    | Place  |Work_Start|  
|:---- |:------:| -----: |    -----:|
|Ester | 27     | Beijing|   8      |     
|Jack  |  29    | Tokyo  |   9      | 
|Mary  | 31     |New_York|   8      |    
|Leo   | 25     |England |   10     |
```

File 2:

```
| Name | Age    | Place  |Work_Start|  
|:---- |:------:| -----: |    -----:|
|Ethan | 29     |Osaka   |  7       |   
|Mary  | 31     |New_York|  8       |         
|Leo   | 25     |England |  9       |
```

I want to extract common rows based on column 1 2 and 3, and write them in separate files.
After extracting, it would be like this

File 1 common:

```
| Name | Age    | Place  |Work_Start|  
|:---- |:------:| -----: |    -----:|
|Mary  |31      |New_York|  8       |           
|Leo   |25      |England |  10      |
```

File 2:

```
| Name | Age    | Place  |Work_Start|  
|:---- |:------:| -----: |    -----:| 
|Mary  |   31   |New_York|  8       |          
|Leo   | 25     |England |  9       |
```

My attempted code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

file1 = open('file1.csv')
file2 = open('file2.csv')
file1_common = open('file1_common.csv', 'w')

file1_r=csv.reader(file1)
file2_r=csv.reader(file2)
file1_common_w = csv.writer(file1_common)


count = 0

file2_set = set()

header1 = next(file1_r)
header2 = next(file2_r)

file1_common_w.writerow(header1)


for row2 in file2_r:
    file2_set.add(row2[0])
    
for row1 in file1_r:
    for row2 in file2_set:
        if (row1[0] in row2[0]) and (row1[1] in row2[1]) and (row1[2] in row2[2]):
            break
    else:
            count=count+1
            file1_common_w.writerow(row1)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

It gave out the File 1 info not common rows.
And for file2_common, I was thinking to reverse row1 and row2.
Would that work?
Thanks for the help.

(I actually use the code as template from another post but I forgot which.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) from `csv` you can get dicts of each row in your csv. Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is a convenient way to pull specific keys from those dicts which will allow you to make tuples of the value that you can add to sets. Doing that, you can just take the intersection:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

getter = itemgetter('Name','Age','Place')

file1 = open(file1_path)
file2 = open(file2_path)

file1_r=csv.DictReader(file1)
file2_r=csv.DictReader(file2)

set(map(getter, file1_r)).intersection(map(getter, file2_r))
```

This will give the set:

```
 {('Leo', '25', 'England'), ('Mary', '31', 'New')}
```

which you can convert back to csv.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
Is there a way that I could get the header of the columns without typing each one into itemgetter?
I actually have other files that have more columns than this.